# Is there a better way to pass values to .replace() than hardcoded regex and strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-chrome-extension, associative-array

I am making a Chrome extension that replaces values on a table on a webpage using jQuery. Now, this normally doesn't represent an issue if I wanted to replace 5-10 values... My problem comes from having to **replace up to 600 values**!

As a background, the extension interacts with a table hosted in a website that has 'Cities IDs' instead of City Names. - It is really difficult for people as they actually need to associate a city number with a city name in their brains.

EDIT: The code looks a bit like this:

```
var $sydney = $('td').html(function(i, html){ return html.replace(/^1$/g, 'Sydney'); });
var $melbourne = $('td').html(function(i, html){ return html.replace(/^2$/g, 'Melbourne'); });
var $perth = $('td').html(function(i, html){ return html.replace(/^3$/g, 'Perth'); });
var $christchurch = $('td').html(function(i, html){ return html.replace(/^4$/g, 'Christchurch'); });
var $canberra = $('td').html(function(i, html){ return html.replace(/^5$/g, 'Canberra'); });
var $newcastle = $('td').html(function(i, html){ return html.replace(/^6$/g, 'Newcastle'); });
var $geelong = $('td').html(function(i, html){ return html.replace(/^7$/g, 'Geelong'); });
var $mornington = $('td').html(function(i, html){ return html.replace(/^8$/g, 'Mornington Peninsula'); });
var $tauranga = $('td').html(function(i, html){ return html.replace(/^9$/g, 'Tauranga'); });
var $hamilton = $('td').html(function(i, html){ return html.replace(/^10$/g, 'Hamilton'); })
```

As you can see, the script searches for matching regex results on the table cells in the HTML ('td') and replaces it with a city name. e.g: Sydney, Melbourne, etc. It worked really well when I had to replace 5-10 values however its performance has decreased a lot since I added those 590 cities.

Is there any way to use an array to pass a value to the .replace() function or am I completely going on the wrong direction?

If the second one, is there any better way to do this without affecting performance as much?

Any suggestions (or answers) would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Comment: you can loop through the array and call `.replace` for each item on the loop

Comment: In this case a [mcve] would include some example HTML against which to run the code.

Comment: You are replacing "values" within the actual HTML using `.replace()` this is almost always a *Bad Idea™*. Are you only needing to replace text? Is what you are replacing also within attributes in the HTML? Please provide example HTML.

Comment: @Makyen - I am not looking to debug, I am looking for better alternatives and I have edited the question title and the question itself to better reflect this. Thank you.

Comment: You could make an object where the the cities are represented by keys, which are exactly the same as the city-codes you're talking about. In this way you would just loop through the cells and use the current value (like `7`) to get the city name (`cities[currentValue]` would resolve to Geelong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an object with all the cities like this:

```
var cities = {
    1: 'Sydney',
    2: 'Melbourne',
    3: 'Perth',
    4: 'Christchurch',
    5: 'Canberra',
    6: 'Newcastle',
    7: 'Geelong',
    8: 'Mornington Peninsula',
    9: 'Tauranga',
    10: 'Hamilton'
}
```

And change your code to this:

```
$('td').html(function(i, html){
  if (cities.hasOwnProperty(html)) {
      return cities[html];
  }
  return html;
});
```

you can reduce your code big time.

```js
var cities = {
  1: 'Sydney',
  2: 'Melbourne',
  3: 'Perth',
  4: 'Christchurch',
  5: 'Canberra',
  6: 'Newcastle',
  7: 'Geelong',
  8: 'Mornington Peninsula',
  9: 'Tauranga',
  10: 'Hamilton'
};

$('td').html(function(i, html) {
  if (cities.hasOwnProperty(html)) {
    return cities[html];
  }
  return html;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>38</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To make it even more fool proof, you probably should add a class to the cells you want your code to affect.

**Edit:**

As user Makyen stated, if you are not certain that the contents of the `td` are the city numbers and nothing else, you could use a regex, or change to the `text()` method of jQuery. Different values require differnent approaches.

Comment: Douwe de Haan, that's beautiful and works really well. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Makyen You're totally right. I'll update my answer later, when I'm behind a computer. Thanks for the tips! Always willing to learn!

Comment: @Makyen I've looked at the regex he used again and he is certain that the html / text inside the `td` is only a number (hence the `^` and the `$`) so I think I let the code as is, but add a note.